# Azure Stream Analytics Reference Input Join

Tags: azure, join, azure-stream-analytics

0

I am trying to use following query to join stream input (deviceinput) and reference input (refinputpdjson):

Following are my Inputs for Stream Analytics Job:

Input 1: Stream Input from IoT Hub
Input 2: Reference Data from Azure Blob Storage

```
SELECT 
din.EventProcessedUtcTime,
din.deviceid as streamdeviceid,
din.heartrate as streamheartrate,
refin.deviceid as refdeviceid,
refin.patientid as refpatientid 
FROM 
deviceinput din 
TIMESTAMP BY EventProcessedUtcTime 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
refinputpdjson refin 
ON din.deviceid = refin.deviceid
```

but its failing with following reasons:

The join predicate is not time bounded. JOIN operation between data streams requires specifying max time distances between matching events. Please add DATEDIFF to the JOIN condition. Example: SELECT input1.a, input2.b FROM input1 JOIN input2 ON DATEDIFF(minute, input1, input2) BETWEEN 0 AND 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Azure service bug. Its resolved by MS Team.
Its working fine now.

Thank you,
Kamlesh Khollam

Answer (score 0):

As error shows,

> JOIN operation between data streams requires specifying max time
> distances between matching events.

So you can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    din.EventProcessedUtcTime, din.deviceid as streamdeviceid, din.heartrate as streamheartrate, refin.deviceid as refdeviceid, refin.patientid as refpatientid 
FROM deviceinput din TIMESTAMP BY EventProcessedUtcTime 
LEFT OUTER JOIN refinputpdjson refin TIMESTAMP BY EventEndUtcTime
ON din.deviceid = refin.deviceid
AND DATEDIFF(minute,din,refin) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
```

More detail, you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/join-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: HI @Steve Zhao,  query join has one stream input and one reference input (and not the two stream inputs). I used the "DATEDIFF" function. But then query editor showing warning message : "Temporal Operators are not allowed with reference data". So its not allowing me to execute the query. After this I selected the query and  "Test Query" button became "Test Selected Query" so executed the query. It shows 0 rows. IoT input and Reference Input does have data for same deviceid. Please suggest if in case I am missing any config for Reference Input

Comment: @KamleshKhollam having the same issue. did you solve the problem?